# How can I bind switches (input checkbox) to a mutually exclusive (input radio) in leaflet.js?

Tags: leaflet

There are three groups of markers (grocery stores, clothing stores, pharmacies). Each of them is from a different company. I need to make a display on the map by stores and their companies. When switching to stores, so that only the selected companies are displayed. That is, when selecting a store, other stores should not be displayed. Input radio -> (grocery stores, clothing stores, pharmacies), input checkbox -> (company1, company2,...). How can I make it so that when selecting, for example, "clothing stores", only the clothing store companies with an optional selection by company are shown?

Comment: Do read https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/ - ignore the naming of "base layers" and focus on the "mutually exclusive" bit.

Comment: thanks. This example does not fit. I should display a different group of markers when changing radio inputs

Comment: Sounds to me that your explanation is still a bit confusing. Adding a small sketch would probably help, or at least more detailed examples.

Comment: I would recommend building an array of objects that have the items stored in them with their geospatial coordinates. When the user clicks the input, you should call a function that loops through the necessary data to plot on the map. You could preload all of the data and then show and hide layers instead of reloading them each time but this will take quite a bit of extra code to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cache-805g6?file=/index.html

This example uses buttons but you could easily switch them to radio buttons if you would rather use those.

The code is quite simple. One page load, it creates the map. I defined a static array of objects that are companies and each company contains objects by store types (yours might be different).

The `doLoadCompany` function takes a the `id` of the company and if it matches, it will loop through the grocery store object for that company and load the markers onto the map. Before it loads the new grocery stores though, it will clear the previously loaded company, if one existed.

This is one simple example. It can get much more complicated depending on your object or it could be simpler again, depending on your object. The basics is to determine a way to identify the company you are wanting to load data for and then load that data. If you're doing this from an API, I would return only the data that you need for the specific company then loop through the data set and plot the markers based on their coordinates.

Comment: I implemented it in my own way, but I like your example better. I am very grateful for your work